# How can I set the log image on header center vertical?

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I want to my logo vertically centralised, however, margin: auto or margin: centre did not work.

What I try(and did not work)
・text-align: center;
・margin: auto;
・margin: centre:
・navbar-brand-center

The logo on the left-top, and the user click the logo image, it will be home.vue(route /).

Now the second photo is that I used margin:-1.8% 0%. but I know it is not an elegant solution.

If you have any idea, please advice me.

```
    <b-navbar-brand :to="`/${$i18n.locale}/`">
         <img :src="image" class="logo"/>
     </b-navbar-brand>
```

```
.logo{
   width: 50px;
   position:absolute;
   height: 50px;
   margin:-1.8% 0%;  
}
```

I want to change from ↓[image]

To this ↓
[image]

Whole code below

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-navbar toggleable="lg" type="light" id="header">

      <b-navbar-brand :to="`/${$i18n.locale}/`">
         <img :src="image" class="logo"/>
      </b-navbar-brand>

      <b-navbar-toggle target="nav-collapse"></b-navbar-toggle>

      <b-collapse id="nav-collapse" is-nav>
          <b-navbar-nav class="center" >
          <b-nav-item :to="`/${$i18n.locale}/`">{{ $t("header.home") }}</b-nav-item>
          <b-nav-item :to="`/${$i18n.locale}/about`">{{
            $t("header.about")
          }}</b-nav-item>
        </b-navbar-nav>

        <!-- Right aligned nav items -->
        <b-navbar-nav class="ml-auto">
            <b-nav-item v-if="!auth" :to="`/${$i18n.locale}/login`">{{
              $t("header.login")
            }}</b-nav-item>
            <b-nav-item v-if="auth" @click="logout()">{{
              $t("header.logout")
            }}</b-nav-item>
            <b-nav-item v-if="!auth" :to="`/${$i18n.locale}/signup`">{{
              $t("header.signup")
            }}</b-nav-item>
            <b-nav-item v-if="auth" :to="`/${$i18n.locale}/profile`">{{
              $t("header.profile")
            }}</b-nav-item>

          <b-nav-item-dropdown text="Lang" right>
            <b-dropdown-item @click="setLocale('en')">ENG</b-dropdown-item>
            <b-dropdown-item @click="setLocale('et')">EST</b-dropdown-item>
          </b-nav-item-dropdown>
        </b-navbar-nav>
      </b-collapse>
    </b-navbar>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import image from "../assets/Logo.jpg"
export default {
  name: "Header",
  data() {
    return {
      image: image
    };
  },
  methods: {
    setLocale(locale) {
      this.$i18n.locale = locale;
      this.$router.push(
        {
          params: {
            lang: locale,
          },
        },
        () => {}
      );
      localStorage.setItem("lang", this.$i18n.locale);
    },
    logout() {
      this.$store.dispatch('logout')
    }
  },
  computed: {
  auth() {
    return this.$store.getters.isAuth
  }
  }
};
</script>

<style>
#header {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}
.logo{
   width: 50px;
   position:absolute;
   height: 50px;
   margin:-1.8% 0%;  
}

@media screen and (max-width: 891px) {
  .center {
    position: relative !important;
}

}

.center {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
</style>
```

Comment: Can I see the css on `b-navbar-brand`?

Comment: Sorry I am just beginner of vue, so I am not sure even where it is. I put my whole code by edit. I have tried ".navbar-brand {text-align: center;}" on CSS but did not work

Comment: Don't use absolute positioning. A quick fix is to use `position: relative` and then set `bottom: 10px` or whatever the appropriate number is.

Comment: It works, how simple it is, thanks!

Comment: @kazy not really responsive tho, since it's hardcoded.

Comment: I think the best way to handle this would be to make the nav menu a flex container with `display: flex` and then use `align-items: center` to ensure that the logo is aligned in the center of the cross-axis. [MDN - Cross Axis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Cross_Axis)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flexbox. It should work. Align items center is vertically align items to center.

```
    #header{ 
    display : flex;
align-items:center;
}
```